# Angular: Accessing viewchildren in child components

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I have a component which has child components (let's take **daypart-hours**):

**Main Component template**

```
- Main Compoennt
-- Sub component 1
--- MatExpansionPanel
-- Sub component 2
--- MatExpansionPanel
--- MatExpansionPanel
--- MatExpansionPanel
```

In my child component daypart hours, there are numerous viewchildren which I need to access (In my case, I need to access all the [material expansion panels](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel)).

So far I have this in my main component

**Main Component TS**

```
@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel)
public _panels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

but this doesn't seem to be able to access the panels in my child components.

Is there anyway I can access every `MatExpansionPanel` from my child components in my main component??

Comment: Did you try to get a reference to your `daypart-hours` in your main component? I think you would need to get a reference to that and then in your `daypart-hours` component get a public list of your expansion panels (`ViewChildren`) that your main component can access on it

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I was thinking of this method aswell, but I was hoping there was a quicker/simpler way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get access to that because components are meant to hide those details (their DOM is kind of like the shadow DOM in the browser).

Comment: @Nicolas, did you access to your child components in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook?